# create or clone checkout/cart block using observer

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, event-observer, blocks

I want to clone the `checkout/cart` block and its children on the cart page, using observer,

When I put below xml code in  `<checkout_cart_index translate="label">` handler it will clone the `checkout/cart` block and it means that in cart page it will display two carts and two proceed to checkout buttons.

I want to do the same dynamically using observer instead. This is the layout XML:

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="insert">
        <block>checkout.cart</block>
    </action>
</reference>
```

My `config.xml`

```
<events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before><!--sales_quote_save_after-->
              <observers>
                <cart_shopping>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>marketplace/observer</class>
                        <method>checkoutCartComplete</method>
                    </cart_shopping>            
              </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
```

My `observer.php`

```
public function checkoutCartComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    { 
        $_block = $observer->getBlock();

        $_type = $_block->getType();

if ($_type == 'checkout/cart') 
{
    $_child = clone $_block;
    $b =  $observer->getBlock()
    ->createBlock('Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart')
    ->setCartTemplate('checkout/cart.phtml')
    ->setEmptyTemplate('checkout/cart/noItems.phtml')
    ->addItemRender("simple", "checkout/cart_item_renderer","checkout/cart/item/default.phtml");

     $child = $observer->getBlock('content')->insert($b);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
$observer->getBlock('content')
```

is wrong. `getBlock` is a magic getter and returns the same `$_block` again, the parameter does nothing.

To retrieve an existing block from the layout by name, use:

```
$_block->getLayout()->getBlock('content')
```

or:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('content')
```

Then you do a few more things in the observer which are probably not necessary. Given that your layout XML code actually works, converted to PHP code it looks like this:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->insert('checkout.cart');
```

Nothing more. You can use the event `controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_cart_index` to apply layout changes in the `checkout_cart_index` route dynamically.